# Bonbons are a mystery

Tags: chocolate, candy

Walmart used to carry gold foil wrapped bonbons, inexpensive that were to die for. I've seen other postings. The outer chocolate, the inner peanut butter melt away is easy. It's the part in between chocolate & peanut butter...a very thin yet crisp wafer coating I can't figure out how to copy. The closest idea I came up with is smashing wafer ice cream cones or wafer sheets...rolling the round melt away ball in them, before dipping in chocolate? I've searched everywhere for ideas & recipes?

Comment: I suspect they make the crispy pastry-like thingy first, then inject the peanut butter, then add the chocolate layer (maybe in a frozen state).

Comment: I don't know how to make them but I think you are looking for Arcor Bon O Bon.